# Passing a file path in curl command

Tags: curl

I'm trying to upload a file to specific machine using the curl command in VBA .I have taken the file path using file dialog and stored it in a varible say sFile.But I'm trying to pass this variable in curl command .Can anyone please help me to resolve this.This is code with command . But it is not substituting the SFile value in the command.

`````
Sub Import()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    enter code here

With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select a CSV file to Upload"
        .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    Dim sFile As String
    If .Show = True Then
        sFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If

End With


Dim strCmd As String
strCmd = Environ$("comspec") & " /c **curl -F fileToUpload=@'$sFile' -H Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml http://00.000.00.000:0000/data/import_csv/**"
Shell strCmd, vbNormalFocus

MsgBox (strCmd)

End Sub
````
`````

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @kookie as stated above, you sould post your code as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Looking at the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/filedialog-members-office) for Show, it returns a `Long` value.

> Displays a file dialog box and returns a Long indicating whether the user pressed the Action button (-1) or the Cancel button (0). When you call the Show method, no more code executes until the user dismisses the file dialog box. In the case of Open and SaveAs dialog boxes, use the Execute method right after the Show method to carry out the user's action.

So your if statement should be

```
if .Show = -1 Then
```

As it is currently, it looks like that if statement would not evaluate to true and set the value to selectedItems